# PHP timezone not converting

Tags: php, datetime

I am using below code to convert the current UTC time/server time in Asia/Calcutta.

```
echo date('Y-m-d h:i:s', time())."-----";
$dateTime = new DateTime (date('Y-m-d h:i:s', time()), new 
DateTimeZone("UTC"));
$dateTime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone("Asia/Calcutta"));
echo $dateTime->format("n/j/Y g:i P");
```

The input is data in first echo is 2017-12-23 15:51:47
Expected output is 12/23/2017 8:21 PM
Actual output is 12/23/2017 8:21 AM

Any comments on this? Why is it doing UTC - 5:30 and not UTC + 5:30 considering Calcutta is 5:30 ahead of UTC?

Comment: It adds 5:30. I see no error in that. 02.51+5.30 is 8.21 AM

Comment: Let me correct the input:
2017-12-23 15:20:24 - input
2017-12-23 08:50:24 - output

Its actually subtracting

Comment: Passing null in DateTime contructor gives me correct output.

Answer (score 0):

```
// set datetime to 2017-12-23 15:51:47, UTC +0:00
$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2017-12-23 15:51:47',
    new DateTimeZone("UTC"));

$datetime->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
// output: "2017-12-23 15:51:47"
$datetime->format("n/j/Y g:i A P");
// output: "12/23/2017 3:51 PM +00:00"

// set timezone to Asia/Calcutta, Eastern Standard Time (EST), UTC +5:30
$datetime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Calcutta'));

$datetime->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
// output: "2017-12-23 21:21:47"
$datetime->format("n/j/Y g:i A P");
// output: "12/23/2017 9:21 PM +05:30"
```